# Why was Jupiter destroyed in "2010: A Space Odyssey" if "A Meeting with Medusa" was a prequel to 2010?

Tags: arthur-c-clarke, 2010-odyssey-two, a-meeting-with-medusa

In the introduction to "*A Meeting with Medusa*", it is mentioned that this is a prequel for "*2010: A Space Odyssey*". If so, why was the life on Jupiter not mentioned in *2010*?

Also, if there was intelligent life on Jupiter, then why was it destroyed by the higher-intelligent people (who made Jupiter into a star)?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The justification for this is given several times over in the books, twice in *2010* alone:

> And because, in all the Galaxy, they had found nothing more precious than Mind, they encouraged its dawning everywhere. They became farmers in the fields of stars; they sowed, and sometimes they reaped.

And sometimes, dispassionately, they had to weed.Life on Jupiter very much **is** mentioned in *2010*, and again — word-for-word — in *2061* and again in *3001*:

> There were jet-propelled torpedoes like the squids of the terrestrial oceans, hunting and devouring the huge gasbags. But the balloons were not defenceless; some of them fought backs with electric thunderbolts and with clawed tentacles like kilometre-long chainsaws.

The opinion of the "farmers" on that life and its prospects is clearly stated in *2010* also:

> […] Jupiter was an evolutionary cul-de-sac. Consciousness would never emerge here; even if it did, it would be doomed to a stunted existence. A purely aerial culture might develop, but in an environment where fire was impossible, and solids scarcely existed, it could never even reach the Stone Age.

Answer (score 20):

Life on Jupiter is in fact mentioned in the novel that the "2010" movie is based on: Bowman's avatar visits both Europa and Jupiter, and finds primitive (not intelligent) life forms in both places. The Monolith's controllers let him know that they consider it very unlikely for the gaseous lifeforms on Jupiter to ever achieve intelligence, but see that potential in the life on Europa. Apparently they have no compuctions about playing god and destroying the lesser life to improve the conditions for that potential.